# Strict mode not working mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I was test in process of testing the strict mode of mongo shell queries. This the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) i am referring.
Sample document looks like -

> > ```
> >    {  "_id" : ObjectId("19876"),
> >     "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
> >     "pgDownloadTime" : NumberLong(25000),
> >     "domain" : "test.domain.com",
> >     "pgAccessTime" : NumberLong("1469422166381"),
> >     "pgAccessMin" : NumberLong(1469422140),
> >     "pgAccessHour" : NumberLong(1469421000),
> >     "contentType" : 1,
> >     "tags" : [
> >             "testTag1",
> >             "testTag2"
> >     ],
> >     "catIds" : [
> >             "cat1",
> >             "cat2"
> >     ]
> > ```

Query using strict mode is -

> > db.testData.find({ "pgAccessMin" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "1469406600" }, "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1469413800" } }, "domain" : "test.domain.com" })

And Query without using strict mode is -

> > db.testData.find({ "pgAccessMin" : { "$gte" : 1469406600, "$lt" :1469413800 }, "domain" : "test.domain.com" })

Issue is that Strict mode query is not providing results but query without strict mode provides the data.
I am using mongo version - 3.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB Extended JSON format allows representation of additional BSON data types that are not part of standard JSON.

There is a subtle distinction between:

- being able to *parse* the extended JSON into a JavaScript representation
- the parser then taking the additional step of *interpreting* the extended key/value pairs into an object with associated JavaScript wrappers such as `NumberLong()` or `Date()`

As per the [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#input-in-strict-mode) page you linked to, the `mongo` shell can parse the strict mode Extended JSON (which conforms to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/)) but *without* recognition of type information:

> Other JSON parsers, including `mongo` shell and `db.eval()`, can parse strict mode representations as key/value pairs, but without recognition of the type information.

The strict mode is only only intended as a data interchange format (for example, transferring a collection via `mongoexport` and `mongoimport`).

For queries in the `mongo` shell you should use the `mongo Shell Mode` representations as noted in the MongoDB Extended JSON documentation.